# Moving data between Neo4j databases

Tags: neo4j

I have to move data between two Neo4j databases. One of them is older (2.1.8) and the new one is 2.3.0.
What I tried is this, but you can see also in the output that something is wrong.

```
/home/adam/neo4j-community-2.1.8/bin/neo4j-shell -path /home/adam/neo4j_bak9/ -c "dump" | /home/adam/neo4j-community-2.3.0/bin/neo4j-shell -file -
Transaction started
3 ms

WARNING: Invalid input 'c': expected whitespace, comment, ';' or end of input (line 2, column 1 (offset: 39))
"create index on :`Location`(`latitude`)"
 ^
ERROR (-v for expanded information):
    Transaction was marked as successful, but unable to commit transaction so rolled back.

 -host      Domain name or IP of host to connect to (default: localhost)
 -port      Port of host to connect to (default: 1337)
 -name      RMI name, i.e. rmi://<host>:<port>/<name> (default: shell)
 -pid       Process ID to connect to
 -c         Command line to execute. After executing it the shell exits
 -file      File containing commands to execute, or '-' to read from stdin. After executing it the shell exits
 -readonly  Connect in readonly mode (only for connecting with -path)
 -path      Points to a neo4j db path so that a local server can be started there
 -config    Points to a config file when starting a local server

Example arguments for remote:
    -port 1337
    -host 192.168.1.234 -port 1337 -name shell
    -host localhost -readonly
    ...or no arguments for default values
Example arguments for local:
    -path /path/to/db
    -path /path/to/db -config /path/to/neo4j.config
    -path /path/to/db -readonly
```

It look that neo4j is producing syntax that could not be read by the new version. Am I doing something wrong or this is a bug?

Answer (score 3):

That's a problem that I've had.  I think that it's expecting semi-colons (or vice versa) for the `create index` statements at the top of the `dump`.  It's sad that it's not more of a smooth import/export there.

Another option for the easiest and cleanest way of upgrading Neo4j (assuming you're able to have a bit of downtime):

- Shut down both servers
- Copy the `graph.db` dir from the old `data` dir to the new one
- Make sure that the new database has `allow_store_upgrade=true` set in the `conf/neo4j.properties` file
- Start up the new database

When it starts up, it should see that the database files are from an old version and automatically upgrade them to the 2.3.0 format.

Comment: some time ago I've created a script that cares about downloads itself and performs the upgrades: http://blog.armbruster-it.de/2012/06/upgrading-an-old-neo4j-database-using-groovy/

Comment: I wrote an shell-extension that does a proper export: https://github.com/jexp/neo4j-shell-tools#cypher-export

Comment: The idea with copying the old database to the new location and setting allow_store_upgrade was my first one. However, there was problem with that. I solved it by going 2.1.8 -> 2.2.6 -> 2.3.0. Still, it is a good thing to have, a simple way to dump database and then load it without additional tools. Original idea looked promising. It is sad that because of this small issue it is not possible. I hope that it is compatible at least 2.3.0 <-> 2.3.0.

Comment: Interesting, I thought you could skip major versions.  Maybe it's just some cases where you can't.  Glad it worked out for you!